# Removing OTP message from keyboard

Tags: swift, keyboard, one-time-password

My textfield read the OTP code from sms message,
if the user press on from message the other textfields work fine, but if the user not use it, the OTP message still appears as suggestion to fill other textfields, so how cloud i remove the OTP from the keyboard when i move to other textfield[image]

Comment: have you tried this ? textField.autocorrectionType = .no

Comment: Yes I had try it but it doesn’t work, even i kill the app the the otp still appears on my app keyboard.

Comment: @A.Munzer have you solved this problem. same issue on my project

Comment: @the_exclusive unfortunately I didn't find the solution